# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to uniqueidentifier is not allowed.

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I am facing this error when i try to edit my text in the ListView and subsequently update it in the database. This error message shows when i click on the update button in my ListView. As my UserID is a uniqueIdentifier, it cannot be updated to my database. But i do not really know what changes to make in my codes.

My error message shows this:

```
Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to uniqueidentifier is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.
```

My SQL Statement in .cs:

```
protected void updateComment(object sender, ListViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{

    MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
    Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

    var ID= ListView1.DataKeys[e.ItemIndex].Value.ToString();

    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ASPNETConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection myConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    string updateSql = "UPDATE Review set ContentRev =@ContentRev WHERE ID = @ID";

    using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        myConnection.Open();

        SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(updateSql, myConnection);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", ID);
        myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentRev ", TextBox1.Text.Trim());

        myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        myConnection.Close();

        ListView1.DataBind();
        }
```

My datatype for Userid is Object and ContentRev is String.

Comment: Not really sure why you mention the user's ID ? It's not part of the SQL.

Answer (score 4):

This is your problem:

```
var ID = ListView1.DataKeys[e.ItemIndex].Value.ToString();
```

If this is a uniqueIdentifier (or GUID), it should read:

```
Guid ID = new Guid(ListView1.DataKeys[e.ItemIndex].Value.ToString());
```

I actually think `var ID` will work, as long as the right side is a GUID.

Comment: Definitively looks like that, which makes it a strange error message.

Comment: I changed to your suggested code but came across this new error: System.FormatException: Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).

Comment: Can you give me an example of what is in the field?

Comment: An example will be this :cc204c82-4c1d-494b-9012-039ce429e7f9

Comment: Then you shouldn't get that exception.

Comment: Now, I encounter a new error which says Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'headings', table